# How to create NSMutableArray of UILabels?

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, uilabel

I have a problem here. I'm creating UILabels dynamically to be displayed into a UIView. Here is the code:

```
for (flower in flowerList)
{               

    // Create the Qty label
    CGRect rectQty = CGRectMake(x , y, 25, labelHeight);
    UILabel *flowerQuantityLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rectQty];
    NSString *fQty = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", flower.flowerQty];
    [flowerQuantityLabel setText:fQty];
    // Loading refrence into a array  
        // here is the problem 
    [flowersQtyLabels addObject:flowerQuantityLabel];

    // Create the name label
    CGRect rectName = CGRectMake((x+offset) , y, labelWidth, labelHeight);
    UILabel *flowerNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rectName];
    [flowerNameLabel setText:flower.flowerName];

    y = y + 40.0;
    [self.view addSubview:flowerQuantityLabel];
    [self.view addSubview:flowerNameLabel];

}
```

- The number of elements in the array changes every time.
- I need to recalculate "flower.flowerQty" and update the result into the label (flowerQuantityLabel).
- I tried to load a reference to each flowerQuantityLabel into a NSMuttableArray (flowersQtyLabels), in order to  change its content with the result of the recalculation.
- At the end of the for, the array flowersQtyLabels is empty. I do not know what the problem is.

I hope some one can help me.

Comment: How do you create flowersQtyLabels and how do you see that it is empty?

Comment: Hi StefanB!!

I created the array as a field of my controller

controller.h
NSMutableArray * flowersQtyLabels;
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *flowersQtyLabels;

controller.m 
@synthesize flowersQtyLabels;

and i know that is empty because I added a NSLog displaying the [flowersQtyLabels count] and is equals to 0.

thanks for your prompt response :)
Alejandra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the `NSMuttableArray` not initialized properly.