# Creating the UITextFields as per array count

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitextfield

I have a mutable array named setUpArray and I want to generate UITextField's  dynamically .The number of textFields  must be equal to [setUpArray count]. I have tried following code . It works 
for generation of UITextFields but problem is they all having the same names. so i can't set the property for individual text independently.

```
  for(int i=0;i<[setUpArray count];i++)
{
    UITextField *nameTextField=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 60, 40)];
   nameTextField.delegate=self;
    [view addSubview:nameTextField];
    y=y+50;


}
```

so please give me the solution on this problem.

Comment: what do you want actually to generate LABELS or TEXTFIELDS ??? heading and description of question is totally different

Comment: Your question is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013325/how-to-create-nsmutablearray-of-uilabels

Comment: i don't think . The problem is different in this question

Comment: why don't you add them to an array? Or set the text property inside this loop?

Answer (score 2):

you may want to use tags to access them later. Just like that:

```
for(int i=0;i<[setUpArray count];i++) {
  UITextField *nameTextField=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 60, 40)];
  nameTextField.delegate=self;
  [view addSubview:label];
  y=y+50;
  nameTextField.tag = 10 + i;
}
```

access it later:

```
UITextField *theTextField = [view viewWithTag:12]; //or any other number
```

Hope it helps

Comment: You're allocating a memory for a number of times (equal to for loop) and yet not releasing it..  :(

Comment: @Hadley that's why there is ARC

Answer (score 0):

You can add :=

```
nameTextField.tag=i;

for(int i=0;i<[setUpArray count];i++)
{
    UITextField *nameTextField=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 60, 40)];
   nameTextField.delegate=self;
   nameTextField.tag = i;
    [view addSubview:nameTextField];
    y=y+50;
}


and access it using :-
if(nameTextField.tag==someIntValue)
{
//perform this operation
}
```